# React-admin's onSave method not passing form values

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am working on a React application and have been using the `react-admin` framework.

I need to pre-process the data coming from a form given that I need separate tables for a new employee and their address but don't want to split it into two screens.

I found the `Using onSave To Alter the Form Submission Behavior` section in the react-admin's [Create/Edit View](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html)  documentation and I applied it to my code (sample below) in hopes that it would allow me to process the data before getting into the dataProvider. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the data out of the form and into the callback for the `CreateEntity` button module.

Create View

```
const CreateActions = props => (
    <TopToolbar {...props}>
        <CreateEntityButton props={props} variant="contained" label={"Create"}/>
    </TopToolbar>
);

const EmployeeCreate = props => (
    <Create {...props} >
    <TabbedForm toolbar={<CreateActions record={props.record} redirect="show" />}>
        <FormTab label="Identity">
            <span >
                <PersonInput />
            </span>
        </FormTab>
        <FormTab label="Address">
            <span >
                <AddressInput />
            </span>
        </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>
    </Create>
)

export default TequitiEmployeeCreate;
```

When I step through the logic in the browser, the callback function in the `handleSave` method (below) passes down `undefined` for both the `values` and the `redirect` parameters. 
I expected the `values` object to contain all the input values from the `TabbedForm` so that it could be parsed and then passed over to my `dataProvider` module.

CreateEntityButton logic:

```
    const CreateEntityButton = ({  ...props}) => {
    const [create] = useCreate(props.props.resource);
    const redirectTo = useRedirect();
    const notify = useNotify();
    const { basePath } = props;

    const handleSave = useCallback(
        (values, redirect) => { // <-------- undefined all the time
            console.log(values);
            console.log(redirect);
            create(
                {
                    payload: { data: { ...values } },
                },
                {
                    onSuccess: ({ data: newRecord }) => {
                        notify('ra.notification.created', 'info', {
                            smart_count: 1,
                        });
                        redirectTo(redirect, basePath, newRecord.id, newRecord);
                    },
                }
            );
        },
        [create, notify, redirectTo, basePath]
    );

    return <SaveButton
        label={props.label}
        variant={props.variant}
        handleSubmitWithRedirect={handleSave}
    />;
};
```

I thought that perhaps having separate modules for `PersonInput` and `AddressInput` was to blame for this, but even consolidating all those components into a single one, didn't help.

Any help/thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, look carefully, you have mixed parts of the code from two different examples in CreateEntityButton, they are not interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks @MaxAlex. I realized that and managed to figure out. Let me close the question with my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I was mixing the example and was using `handleSubmiutWithRedirect` instead of the `onSave` action in the SaveButton.

```
const CreateEntityButton = ({  ...props}) => {
        const resource = props.props.resource;
    const redirectTo = useRedirect();
    const notify = useNotify();
    const { basePath } = props.props;
    const dataProvider = useDataProvider();

    const handleSave = useCallback(
        (values) => {
            const createPerson =  new PersonAddressCreate(dataProvider);
            createPerson.create(values, resource)
                .then((data)=>{
                    notify('ra.notification.created', 'info', { smart_count: 1 });
                    redirectTo("show", basePath, data.id, data)
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    notify(error, 'error', { smart_count: 1 });
                })

        },
        [notify, redirectTo, basePath]
    );


    return <SaveButton
        {...props.props}
        label={props.label}
        variant={props.variant}
        onSave={handleSave}
    />;
};
```